# Advanced Filtering in Excel, Search Multiple Text Conditions in 1 column

Tags: excel, filter

I have two columns similar to this and want to search for both "pineapple" and the "ana" to get the result Kate. I have attempted to use advanced search but found this will get all 3 of these names if I do or don't use the wildcard symbol *. I have also tried the filter function available in Excel but cannot filter based on multiple AND (I think it's AND?) criteria with the wildcard.

| Name | Basket |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | Apple, Banana |
| Jim | Apple, Pineapple, Bread |
| Kate | Pineapple, bread, Banana |

I also have this data available in a table format where each name and item is on a separate line rather than on the same line with commas

Is there a way I can filter my data based on multiple AND criteria in a single column with or without the use of the wildcard? Maybe searching "pineapple" and "banana" to get the result Kate?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `FILTER()` like below-

```
=FILTER(A2:A4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Pineapple",B2:B4))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ana",B2:B4))))
```

[image]

Comment: You are amazing! Can you please explain the use of ISNUMBER and SEARCH and their interaction with FILTER? SEARCH looks for the position of the character like "ana" in the string and will return a number which which ISNUMBER sees as TRUE. But how does this work together with FILTER to find Kate? Doesn't FILTER need some sort of text value to search for where your ISNUMBER(SEARCH( formula begins?

Comment: FILTER function works based on Boolean logic. So when both ISNUMBER return `TRUE` then `TRUE*TRUE=TRUE` and then FILTER function return corresponding cells from array.

Comment: This article will help more [Filter formula tips by exceljet](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function)

Comment: Thanks very much you Excel wizard. I see that this is only available in Excel 365 according to the website that you have linked. Does this mean that it is not available in any of the desktop versions? If I wanted to write this into a local Excel document are there other options? If not it's no problem, I will continue to use this online version :))

Comment: It is also available to Office365 desktop version but not not available to other older version like Excel2019, 2016 and older. For older version you need some complex array formula which will make excel performance slower for large dataset.